# Why does AutoHotkey respond with a "System cannot find the file" error?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotkey and cannot understand why this script is giving me the error:

```
 Failed to launch program or document
 Action: <C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe>
 Params: <* "Initiated.">
 Specifically: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here is the simple script in my test.ahk file:

```
Run, "C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe" * "Initiated."
```

I've verified that the msg.exe file is in the c:\Windows\System32 folder and I can run it without the script from both a command prompt and by clicking on the msg.exe program.  I can also create a shortcut for msg.exe and it works, but I cannot figure out how to get the test.ahk script file to see it.

I tried running the script (by clicking on the test.ahk file), as Administrator but get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That path gets redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for 32-bit programs.

Try changing the path in your script to `"C:\Windows\SysNative\msg.exe"`

Or better yet, don't put non-system files in directories owned by the OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP means [this msg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html). At  least in Windows 7 Enterprise, it's only distributed as a 64-bit program in System32; there's no 32-bit build in SysWow64.

Comment: @ChrisGciso, apparently AutoHotkey is a 32-bit program, for which accessing the System32 directory gets redirected to SysWow64, as Ben already explained.

Comment: Btw, the reason I use the 32bit autokey.exe is for compatibility reasons so that people with a 32bit O/S can run my scripts.  Autokey tells me that if I use the 64 bit version, those 64 bit compiled scripts won't run on 32 bit systems.

Comment: What's autokey.exe?  You can compile AutoHotkey scripts for 32-bit systems while using AutoHotkey 64-bit on your own system.  Just select a 32-bit option from the "Base File" drop-down in the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisGciso I had a similar problem with autohotkey, could not start a program located in `c:\windows\system32`. Changing it to `c:\windows\sysnative` helped - Now that's really interesting, how windows does that directory renaming for compatibility reasons!