# Why can't "Pause::Run notepad++ non_system_file" work?

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, notepad

How to run this command properly?

```
Pause::Run notepad++ D:\Data\Config\Essential.ahk
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed attempt to launch program or document:
Action: <notepad++ D:\Data\Config\Essential.ahk>
Params: <>

Specifically: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Using Notepad++ for any key, or <kbd>Pause</kbd> key with notepad doesn't work. This doesn't involve system directories, as talked in this related question ([Why does AutoHotkey respond with a "System cannot find the file" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798635/3416774)). Do you have any idea?

Full error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHK cannot know that "notepad++" is a program, if you don't use the .exe extension, therefore the error message "The system cannot find the **file** specified".

Try also

```
Pause::Run notepad++.exe D:\Data\Config\Essential.ahk
```

or

```
Pause::Run notepad++.exe "D:\Data\Config\Essential.ahk" ; more accurate syntax
```

Comment: why does this work on Run dialog? Using `Run explorer /path` works as expected

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The following launches the executable "notepad++.exe" without problem even though the `EXE` extension is omited: `F2::run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++" c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I think, in this case AHK finds out that "notepad++" is a program, because of (= after searching in) the folder path definition and the name of the file itself, as explained in the manual  ([Run_Parameters_Target](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#Parameters)).

Answer (score 2):

Is "notepad++.exe" in your path?

Try specifying the full path to notepad++.exe and see if that fixes it:

```
Pause::run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" D:\Data\Config\Essential.ahk
```

NOTES:

- make sure notepad++.exe is installed in the above directory
- you can locate notepad++.exe by opening a command prompt and running `cd \ && dir notepad.exe /s`
- Use a command prompt and enter `set path` to see if notepad++.exe's directory is in your path